# mod_rewrite the page name towice when i click on link

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

when i enable mod_rewrite it works properly when i click on link second time it the page name showed in url twicw like: /secure/UITA/video/video/showlibrary/1/4/4
video is my php page

please give me the solution

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+video\.php\?task=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ video/%1? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^video/([\w-_:]+)/?$ video.php?task=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+video\.php\?task=([^\s&]+)&vendorid=([^&]*)&certid=    ([^&]*)&examid=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ video/%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^video/([\w-_:]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)?$ video.php?task=$1&vendorid=$2&certid=$3&examid=$4 [L,NC,QSA]


# PHP hiding rule

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: That is unrelated to rewrite rules. You need to make sure to use absolute URLs like `href="/video/showlibrary/1/4/4"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```